# div image is overriding other images in other div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have one big image whose size is unknown to me. size varies with every image so i cant define the width and height of images. but the image is in particular div and i expect it to be in its div but it overflows and shown above other images,. however in dreamweaver it shows as expected.

```
       http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/photos-slideshow.php/2786608/hill-photo
```

the css of that div is

```
 .detail_view_m {margin: 0 auto;position: relative;text-align: center;}
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You want to set the height and width for div and to give a scroll if the image is bigger than the dimensn of div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need those images to show has a thumbnail (maybe slider) or you need that each div use it's child image dimensions?

Case 1: set dimensions for your divs, use each image has a background-image and use background-size:cover; to make sure that each image will fit in your div keeping its aspect ratio

```
.detail_view_m {
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-size:cover;
}

<div class="detail_view_m" style="background-image:url(http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/photos-slideshow.php/2786608/hill-photo)">
</div>
```

Case 2: Show each image has a block and your divs will use those dimensions

```
.detail_view_m img{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: large image i want to show inside div. i tried case 2 but it does not work. case 1 i cant try as i cant define dimension.thx

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and set height and width of sliding image.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for you.you shoud use a `div` as image container and give it `width` and `height` what you want.then put your `img` inside it and then give `width` and `height` for it.try this code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome !</title>

<style type="text/css">
   div.imagecontainer{
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
    
   }

   div.imagecontainer img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;
   }


</style>
</head>

 <body>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREn2n3e1C4jSJE7In1OjHC7ACsa2YDMYZYzzhKUzVz89r9utFZGdRI7CGJ">
  </div> 
 

 </body>

</html>
```

hope this will help to you.

Comment: its skewing the images so cant use

Comment: what do you mean bye skew.if your image is in online, send me the image link

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
.detail_view_m {
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 overflow:scroll;
  }
```

This will set a dimension for your div and enable scroll if your image exceeds the dimensions of the div.